# How do I get the {{id}} from the url in express +Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I'm trying to create a CRUD app using Node and express, i'm relatively new to it. I have an ideas page and an edit button on each idea. I keep on getting the error "Cannot GET /ideas/edit1/" when I click the edit button(this view exists by the way).

Here's the code I used to edit data in a form:

```
app.get('/ideas/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    Idea.findOne({
            _ id: req.params.id
        })
        .then(idea => {
            res.render('ideas/edit1', {
                idea: idea
            });
        });

})
```

I have checked the express documentation and i'm pretty sure express uses the : to denote a variable in a route.

I'm wondering what else to do.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Do you know how `res.render` function works?

Comment: There is space between _ and id. Is It also in the code or did you do it by mistakenly?

Comment: kmkm: there is no space in code, I must have added it while pasting the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your form, maybe you are not passing the id correctly.

Comment: form looks okay.

Comment: Then console log your id and the result to see which step is not passing.

Comment: please dont use an `answer` post , this is merely a clarification comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  res.render('ideas/edit1'
 you should be using  res.render('ideas/edit/1')

Comment: if you can tell me, what are you trying to achieve here, maybe I can help you out.

Comment: Otherwise, you can dynamically generate pages using your template engine like EJS.

Comment: Puneet Chandiok: I'm trying to make edit existing posts using an edit form. I'm trying to get the id of each post dynamically from the url to edit that particular post